# IR LED Safety: Where does this OSRAM App note (AN090) formula come from?

Tags: led, safety, infrared, light, radiation

The formula is from OSRAM application note [AN090](https://dammedia.osram.info/media/resource/hires/osram-dam-2496541/Eye%20Safety%20of%20IREDs%20used%20in%20Lamp%20Applications.pdf) "Eye safety of IREDs used in lamp applications":

$$ L_{ir} \approx \frac{I_e R(\lambda)}{Z^2} $$

In the app note, they don't give a reference for it.  It's an approximation for:

$$ L_{ir} =  \sum_{\lambda=780}^{1400} L_\lambda \cdot R(\lambda) \cdot \Delta\lambda $$

Why and how does the approximation work?

Does it work for any IRED, planar or edge?  I'm specifically interested in if it applies to a 5mm T1 IRED (edge emitters?) since the app note only has examples for planar emitters.

Strangely, I've found at least one other "eye safety" app note that repeats the approximation formula and attributes it to this particular app note.

---

I should clarify.  What I'm really asking is how:

$$ L_\lambda \approx \frac{I_e}{Z^2} $$

\$ Z^2 \$ in this case is the 'emitter area'.  The app note uses the chip area and the Radiant Intensity from the datasheet of the IRED.  They show that the measured and calculated Radiance are the same in this table: [image: Figure 2]

As I understand it, the Radiant Intensity from the datasheet is measured from the apparent source.  And in the appendix of that appnote, they show that:

$$ \frac{A_{chip}}{A_{LED}} = \frac{I_{chip}}{I_{LED}} $$

Despite this, they give a formula for Radiance using the Radiant Intensity of the apparent source and the area of the emitter source.

If I take a real LED like the [TSAL7600](https://media.digikey.com/pdf/Data%20Sheets/Vishay%20Semiconductors/TSAL7600.pdf) which has the apparent source size in the datasheet (a rare thing):

[image: apparent source]

They don't list the chip or emitter size.  It has been pretty difficult to find the emitter size of a 5mm LED.  I've seen 0.2mmx0.2mm and 0.3mmx0.3mm floating around, but the apparent source size (1.8mm) is at least 6 times larger and 36 times more area.  And using it would, in the case of table 2 above, give the wrong result.

---

A new discovery that will hopefully shed some light.  Vishay has a [document](https://www.vishay.com/docs/led_measure.pdf) on how the radiant intensity is measured:
[image: radiant intensity measurement]

It is measured over an angle 0.01sr which is small like the eye safety standard requires.  The detector area is 1 square centimetre though and I don't know how well that maps to the retina or pupil area.

Using the peak radiant intensity seems justified in this case, but I still don't see why they divide by the emitter area.  I'm still missing something.